# Using reactive extensions for a simulation engine

Tags: simulation, system.reactive

How would you structure a simple simulation engine using Reactive Extensions? For example, suppose you had a class `Motor` with properties `IsPowered` and `Speed`. You want to react to `IsPowered` changing from false to true by having `Speed` ramp up from 0 to 1000 RPM by 10 RPM each second for 100 seconds.

Abstracting this a bit, suppose you want to provide a pluggable API where the class and its properties aren't known in advance. Instead, the simulation engine gets an observable stream of property changes which is reacts to by creating additional property changes, many of which take place in increments over time leveraging Rx. What might such an API look like?

Comment: Are you expecting the engine to poll for changes on properties or will the model expose events or observables to notify changes?

Comment: The model will expose events or observables that properties (e.g. `IsPowered`) have changed. (As to which of events or observables is better, that is part of the guidance I'm looking for.)

Comment: So, in your example, the `Motor` class would have a `IsPoweredObservable` and `SpeedObservable` properties (or the equivalent events) as well as the `IsPowered` and `Speed` properties?

Comment: Yes, along those lines. For consuming property changes, I think you'd expose `IObserver` rather than `IObservable` per the [IObservable/IObserver Development Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362412.aspx). Combining the two and abstracting the properties, would something like a `Subject<PropertyChange>` work?

Comment: Don't expose observers - any stray bit of code can call `OnCompleted` or `OnError` and turn your application into mush. Subjects are also observers so also don't expose them.

Comment: Agree with @Enigmativity. Exposing Subject<T> is a terrible idea - any code from the outside can send out messages to all your subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simulation API would need a type to represent property changes and a simulation method that had an incoming and outgoing `IObservable<T>` stream of changes. The implementation of the simulation engine would consist of rules that reacted to incoming property changes to update the output stream.

The type would be like this (although a struct would probably be better than a class):

```cs
class PropertyChange
{
    public PropertyChange(string name, object value) { Name = name; Value = value; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }
}
```

The simulation method would look like the following. To demonstrate multiple rules, this code presupposes a property `IsLightOn` that simply tracks `IsPowered`.

```cs
IObservable<PropertyChange> Simulate(IObservable<PropertyChange> incomingChanges)
{
    var isLightOnRule =
        from c in incomingChanges
        where c.Name == "IsPowered"
        select new PropertyChange("IsLightOn", c.Value);

    var ramp = Observable.Generate(0, speed => (speed <= 1000), speed => speed + 10, speed => new PropertyChange("Speed", speed), _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var speedRule = incomingChanges
        .Where(c => c.Name == "IsPowered" && (bool)c.Value)
        .SelectMany(ramp);

    // Add more rules here.

    return Observable.Merge(isLightOnRule, speedRule /* merge more rules here */);
}
```